# PHP Redirect after Mysql Insert

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my mySQL insert:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO gj (name, phone, city, zipcode, description, dateadded, website, address1, other2, payment_options, Products, email,cat1,cat2,cat3)
    VALUES
    ('$companyname','$phone','$city','$zipcode','$description',curdate(),'$website','$address','$other','$payment','$products','$email','$select1','$select2','$select3')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "<br/><h2><font color='green' style='font-size:15px;float:right'>1 business added</font></h2>";

    mysql_close($link);
}

    ?>
```

Now, instead of displaying "1 business added" in green, I'd like to redirect back to the page I was on before. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script is always intended to go to the same place afterwards, then you can hard-code the location.  For example:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Note that per RFC 2616 (the HTTP/1.1 specification), the value of the `Location` header must be an absolute URI, not just a path.

If your script is for a specific purpose and always redirects to a certain section, but may vary which particular records are shown, then you can incorporate the data that was posted to your script into the URL.  For example:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/widgets/" . urlencode($_POST['id']));
```

If your script is used in several different ways, then you can pass along the URL to redirect to from the page that posts to it in a hidden form field, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect-url" value="http://www.example.com/">
```

More generally, you should follow the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
header("Location: page_you_want.php");
```

after your query has completed but before anything is echo'ed. You can only use the above code if headers have not already been sent including HTML etc.

Comment: Here is my code but I'm still getting an error    $sql="INSERT INTO gj (name, phone, city, zipcode, description, dateadded, website, address1, other2, payment_options, Products, email,cat1,cat2,cat3)
  VALUES
  ('$companyname','$phone','$city','$zipcode','$description',curdate(),'$website','$address','$other','$payment','$products','$email','$select1','$select2','$select3')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  mysql_close($link);
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 }

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

after

```
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: I get this error                                  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Sites/gj/doctype.php:5) in /Users/Sites/gj/addbusiness.php on line 98....and line 98 is is where I put the header('location....stuff you just gave me?? Is there any thing I might be doing wrong?

Comment: location can be set to any web address. be sure not to output anything to the browser before setting a header or you will get an error (this includes blank lines not encased in <?php ?>).

Comment: yeah, that error means that you outputted something to the browser before you set the header. don't do that.

Comment: Don't do this, the Referer header is not reliable.

Comment: you need to get rid of the echo statement or the header wont work.