# php mysql error handling display in error in error page

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, error-handling

```
$postQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * from table_name order by column desc")or die(mysql_error());
```

When there is error in query it ends the control and shows the error message in same page..

i want to redirect to an error page when error occurs and display the error in that page.

here is my Code  :

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        header("Location: ".SITEURL."/error.php?message=" . url_encode($conn->connect_error));
    }
```

Any Suggestion.

Comment: Is this related to [PHP Redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663688/php-redirect-after-mysql-insert)

Comment: Yes, its php $conn->query() function.

Comment: just use an `if/else`

Comment: Yes @Ghost. but how can i send error information to another page.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your mysql query fails, it returns a `False`, and the connection holds the error data, which you can reference as such:

```
if (!$conn->query("SELECT * from table_name order by column desc")) {
  header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/error.php?errormessage=" . url_encode($conn->error));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general error handler, suitable for any type of errors

Add this in the page where error is being generated

```
 //error handler function
 function customError($errno, $errstr) {
       $errorpage= "Location:error.php?&err=".$eerrno." ". $errstr;
 }

 //set error handler
 set_error_handler("customError");
```

Now make the page to display your error,

error.php

```
<?php
$err=$_GET['err'];
echo $err;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
try {
    $postQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * from table_name order by column desc")or die(mysql_error());
} catch (MySQLException $e) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/");
}
```

If you get another error than MySQLException, then just replace that exception.